# Error while searching text in drupal site with apache solr

Tags: solr, drupal-7

Indexing mysql database with apache solr was completed successfully and it works in the solr admin area.

But i could not search any text in my drupal site, it returns the error message "**Search is temporarily unavailable. If the problem persists, please contact the site administrator.**"
Even after configured in apache solr search form in the admin panel of drupal site ("*admin/config/search/apachesolr*").

At that moment the following error was displayed in solr admin: "**org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field hash**".

For the above error i included the following code in schema.xml file,
"< field name="hash" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>"

and then later i received the new error as like below,
"**org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field access__all**".

Is need to do any additional configuration in our drupal site for search using apache solr? why this would happen? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How have you indexed the database? Have you used apachesolr.module's built-in way of indexing or have you used a DIH of some kind to directly index data from your DB?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used apachesolr modules not DIH. is it possible to index entire mysql database instead of using individual entity for each table?